# How to get full AJAX URL request after Ajax.BeginForm complete?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, url

In my code, when user presses the submit button, it will execute an AJAX request to the controller.

It's all doing fine, however, I also wanted to update the browser URL to include the full query string (e.g. http://localhost/Forecast?BillingToes=123&Year=2016).

The Controller is returning a partial view with a model. Adding an additional property containing the full URL with query string seems to be OK. However, it seems pretty awkward.

So my question is, is there a way to retrieve the full URL via JavaScript after OnComplete? Below is my View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForecast", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "forecastControlPart",
    LoadingElementId = "ajaxSpinnerImage",
    OnBegin = "DeactivateForm",
    OnSuccess = "initAppendHeader();UpdateURL(xhr)",
    OnComplete = "ReloadFiltersBehaviour"
}, new
{
    @class = "onChangeForm",
    data_currencyurl = @Url.Action("GetCurrencyForBilling", "DataSource"),
}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, using $(form).serialize() can fetch all the parameters the form submit to the server, so my code would look like:

In my View:

> ```
> @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForecast", null, new AjaxOptions {
> HttpMethod = "POST",
> InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
> OnSuccess = "initAppendHeader(),UpdateURL(this)",
> }))
> ```

In my Javascript file:

> ```
> function UpdateURL(form) {
> // Auto-Update browser URL to include parameters after submit.
> var formData = $(form).serialize();
> window.history.pushState(null, null, formData);
> }
> ```